# display a hidden input field when enter value on a particuloar input filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

anyone could help me out on how i could achieve this with either javascript or jquery maybe to get the following as mentioned below

say i have this field1

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="">
```

and then i have this field2

```
<input type="hidden" name="field2" value="">
```

what i mean to say the field2 should be hidden but if someone enters some value in field1 then field2 shows but if no value on field1 then it disappears?

thanks in advance and appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd get the first field, check if it has a value, and toggle the second field based on that, but you should not be using a hidden input, but instead hide it with CSS

```js
$('[name="field1"]').on('input', function() {
    var el = $('[name="field2"]').toggle( this.value !== "" );

    if (this.value === "") el.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="field1" value="" placeholder="type something">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="field2" value="" style="display:none">
```

Comment: don't seem to be working mate no affect is taking place when enter calue

Comment: @johrampong - really, when you click "run code snippet" and type something, it doesn't show the second input ?

Comment: sorry here it is working but i tried on a html file i dont know nothing is happening

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('[name="field1"]').on('input', function() {
    $('[name="field2"]').toggle( this.value !== "" );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" placeholder="type something">
<br>
<input type="text" name="field2" value="" style="display:none">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And you're sure you have the right link to jQuery, you seem to be missing the protocol part.

Comment: i tired the exact link to jquery you provided, what am i doing wrong that its not working on my html file?

Comment: You're missing the `https://` part, the closing script tag, and a DOM ready handler when you put the script in the head -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/m4ng6y2n/

Comment: ah you are right sorry for the trouble and really very thankful mate appreciate it

Comment: one last trouble if say i remoce value on first field how can i clear values already entered on the field2?

Comment: I've added that to the answer above as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you've also tagged your question with JavaScript it seems worth offering the following:

```
// retrieving the first - if any - element with its
// 'name' attribute equal to the value of 'field1':
var input = document.querySelector('[name=field1]');

// adding an event-listener to that element, listening
// for the 'input' event (keyup, paste, copy...) and
// assigning the method's anonymous function as the
// event-handler:
input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  // 'e': here unused, is a reference to the event
  // which triggered the function to be called; using
  // e.type will give the specific event, if required
  // (and other properties are, of course, available).

  // retrieving the first - if any - element with has
  // its 'name' attribute equal to 'field2':
  var conditionalInput = document.querySelector('[name=field2]');

  // if the value of the <input> element that received
  // the event has a value that, when leading and trailing
  // white-space is removed, results in a truthy
  // evaluation (the string length is non-zero):
  if (this.value.trim().length) {

    // we set the display style of the conditionally-
    // shown <input> to 'block', you could instead use
    // 'inline-block' if you prefer:
    conditionalInput.style.display = 'block';

  // otherwise, if the length of the trimmed-value is
  // zero (falsey):
  } else {

    // we set the display style of the conditionally-
    // shown <input> to 'none':
    conditionalInput.style.display = 'none';

    // and also remove its entered value:
    conditionalInput.value = '';
  }
});
```

```js
var input = document.querySelector('[name=field1]');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

  var conditionalInput = document.querySelector('[name=field2]');
  if (this.value.trim().length) {
    conditionalInput.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    conditionalInput.style.display = 'none';
    conditionalInput.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" />

<input type="text" name="field2" value="" />
```

In your HTML please note that I've adjusted the `<input>` element's `type`, from 'hidden' to 'text', this is because some browsers – I believe mostly Internet Explorer – has, or had, issues when changing the `type` of an `<input>` element dynamically.

If your use-case doesn't depend on cross-browser compatibility then you can, of course, change the `type` (`conditionalInput.type = 'text'`/`conditionalInput.type = 'hidden'`) rather than the `display`.